# Getting unwanted signals/input from terminal in c program

Tags: c, linux, pthreads, system, interprocess

I written c program in the below concepts.

`main_process.c`

```
   /* check the give process id is alive or not. if not alive then start that process.*/
   void * thread1()
   {
     while(1) {
       if (kill(pid, 0)!=0) {
         system(process1);
       }
     }
   }

  /* Get the process id for the started process */
   void *thread2() {
     while (1) {
       FILE *fp = popen("ps -af | grep "process1");
       get_pid(pid, fp);
       pclose(pid);
     }
   }

   get_pid(pid, fp) {
     /*  Get the pid for the new process using getline() and string parsing using string token function, its long code so not pasted here.*/
   }

   main(int arg, char *args[]) {
     pthread_t tid1, tid2;
     pthread_create(tid1,NULL, &thread1, NULL);
     pthread_create(tid2, NULL, &thread2, NULL);
     //Checks thread created success or not.
     pthread_join(tid1);
     pthread_join(tid2);
   }
```

`process:`

```
   main() {
     char input[100];
     while (1) {
       fgets(input, 100, stdin);
       printf("\n Input is %s \n", input);
     }
```

I started the `process` program first, and get the `pid` and starting the `main_process`.
After some time I killed the `process` program using `kill -9 pid`. So the if condition of `thread1` in `main_process` passed and starts the `process` program.

Getting inputs from the terminal. After some time I again killed the `process` program using `kill -9 pid`. So `thread1` again starts the `process` program.

Issue is the following: When the `process` program starts for the second time, getting unwanted inputs from terminal. I have no idea about who's sending, issue in keyboard or in my program concepts.

Please inform where I made mistakes.

Comment: Your question is  incomplete and has some mistakes - forcing the readers to make assumptions.
what get_pid()  does and how it works? Is it a custom function you've written?
Where you're closing[ pclose() ] after doing the popen() ?

Comment: get_pid is getting pid for new process. using getline() and string token function will get the pid. its long code. so not pasted here. Pls understand the functionality.